# What is wrong with my junction.exe command?

Tags: windows, junction

I am trying to create a junction point on windows 8 so that files will be written on my HDD (D:) instead of my SSD (C:).

A few of the commands I've tried

```
D:\Downloads\Junction\junction.exe D:\Temp\Glasswire\service C:\ProgramData\GlassWire\service
D:\Downloads\Junction\junction.exe D:\Temp\Chrome\LocalStorage "C:\Users\Garvin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage"
```

The end result is that files are written to both the junction point directory and the destination directory. My understanding of junction points was that new files would only be written to the junction point directory, but are junction points actually just backup directories or am I doing something wrong here?

(Also I am using Windows 8)

**EDIT:** From what I see in task manager/Performance only my SSD shoots up in activity when dragging files to C:\Users\Garvin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage while the HDD stays at 0%. (I am dragging a 550mb video and 700mb exe from a USB)

I was attempting to reduce the number of writes the SSD performs to increase its lifespan but junction points do not seem to be the way to go, contrary to what is written here http://lifehacker.com/5802838/how-to-maximize-the-life-of-your-ssd

Comment: No, the files aren't being written to both places.  The junction point just makes it look as if they are.  That's how it's supposed to work - you can read from a junction point as well as write to it.

Comment: When I look at the properties of any of the files, there isn't any evidence that the junction point is working. I'm just finding it hard to believe but would you know a source I could refer to for this?

Comment: If the files are appearing on the target drive, the junction point is working.  If you're uncertain, though, create a large file and observe that the free disk space on the source drive doesn't change.

Comment: From what I see in task manager/Performance only my SSD shoots up in activity when dragging files to C:\Users\Garvin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage while the HDD stays at 0%. (I am dragging a 550mb video and 700mb exe from a USB)

Comment: I also tried downloading a new torrent (different 550mb video) and only my SSD is showing writing activity

Comment: Which way around are the junction points?  The commands you show in your question are back to front: they create a junction point *from* drive D *to* drive C, so the data will be written on drive C.  I think that's your problem.

Comment: @HarryJohnston You are right, the direction was the problem. Switching the direction produced the effect I wanted. If you write your solution as an answer, I can choose it as correct if you want. The problem is all fixed now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the built-in `mklink /j` command to create directory junctions in Windows. It seems to work fine -- just like a soft link in Linux.

Hese's some info from TechNet here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx

Comment: Harry Johnston posted a comment above saying that even though it looks like it's being written to both places it's not? Are you getting the same thing where files are being written to both the junction point directory and the destination directory? I'm just having a tough time verifying the junction point is doing what it's suppose to (only writing to the junction point directory and not to the destination directory)

Comment: You can test that the junction is working correctly by deleting a file from one or the other -- try it from the "real" directory, for example -- and verify that the file is no longer visible from the other path.

Comment: Also, if you view the junction in Windows Explorer, it will have a different icon than a true directory.

Comment: I do see that they are linked and deleting one deletes the other but when I am writing large files (550mb video + 700mb exe), my task manager/Performance only shows my SSD drive shooting up in activity

Comment: Perfect. It sounds like it's working as expected then. What you've done is create something you can think of as a "view" to another location. Or a different path that you can use to access a location.

Comment: Darn, I was trying to reduce the number of writes on the SSD to increase its lifespan according to http://lifehacker.com/5802838/how-to-maximize-the-life-of-your-ssd but I guess that advice doesn't work